# bank account client in java with multiple classes

Tags: java, class, object, bank

I am trying to make a bank account program, but I cannot figure out how to get all my variables visible to every class that I have, or how to make the withdrawal and deposit methods of my code visible. Can anyone look at my code and tell me what is wrong? I only want input and output in the client class.

Thanks

## Client Class

```
public class Client {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);       
    System.out.println("Enter your Name: ");
    String cusName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Account Type: ");
    String type = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Initial Balance: ");
    int bal = input.nextInt();
    BankAccount b1 = new BankAccount(cusName, num, type, bal);
    int menu;
    System.out.println("Menu");
    System.out.println("1. Deposit Amount");
    System.out.println("2. Withdraw Amount");
    System.out.println("3. Display Information");
    System.out.println("4. Exit");
    boolean quit = false;
    do {
      System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
      menu = input.nextInt();
      switch (menu) {
      case 1:
        b1.deposit();
        break;

      case 2:
        b1.withdraw();
        System.out.println("Current Account Balance=" + Balance);
        System.out.print("Enter withdrawal amount:");
        amount = input.nextInt();
        break;

      case 3:
        b1.display();
        break;

      case 4:
        quit = true;
        break;
      }
    } while (!quit);
  }
}
```

## Money Class

```
public class Money
{

  static int accountNumber, Balance, amount;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  static String name, actype;
  public int deposit() {
    System.out.print("Enter depost amount:");
    amount = input.nextInt();
    if (amount < 0) {
      System.out.println("Invalid");
      return 1;
    }
    Balance = Balance + amount;
    return 0;
  }

  int withdraw()  {

    if (Balance < amount) {
      System.out.println("Not enough funds.");
      return 1;
    }
    if (amount < 0) {
      System.out.println("Invalid");
      return 1;
    }
    Balance = Balance - amount;
    return 0;
  }

}
```

## BankAccount Class

```
class BankAccount {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  static String name, actype;
  static int bal, amt;
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  int accNo = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);

  BankAccount(String name, int accNo, String actype, int bal) {
    this.name = name;
    this.accNo = accNo;
    this.actype = actype;
    this.bal = bal;
  }
  void display() {
    System.out.println("Name:" + name);
    System.out.println("Account No:" + accNo);
    System.out.println("Balance:" + bal);

  }

  void dbal() {
    System.out.println("Balance:" + bal);
  }
}
```

Comment: Last Week it was the Students Homework, this week it seems to be the BankAccount homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add `Money` to your `BankAccount` and create a getter method as:

   ```
   class BankAccount {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      static String name, actype;
      static int bal, amt;
      Random randomGenerator = new Random();
      int accNo = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
      Money money;

      BankAccount(String name, int accNo, String actype, int bal) {
       this.name = name;
       this.accNo = accNo;
       this.actype = actype;
       this.bal = bal;
       this.money = new Money();
     }

     public Money getMoney(){
        return this.money;
     }
     .....
   }
   ```
2. Use `bankaccount.getMoney()` to invoke `deposit` and `withdraw` as :

   ```
    b1.getMoney().deposit();
    b1.getMoney().withdraw();
   ```

In addition, **I would advice to make the `Money` class attributes e.g. amount, accntType... non-static** and set through through a constructor. Static variables are associated with class definition and hence you won't be abl to maintain them per Bank Account.

Comment: @RickyMcQuesten If helpful then don;t forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to answer this question for you. Instead, I'm going to recommend that you read a bit more about Java programming concepts that will explain it to you, by default.

- [Here is one on encapsulation, which is the main concept that you're asking about](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm)
- [This is a great book on how to write code well, including things like keeping methods short](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

  - In particular, your main method should be broken into smaller pieces
  - Here's a [stack overflow question that talks about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065044/smaller-methods) if you don't want to buy the book.

If you don't want to read any of these links, @YogendraSingh answered this question really well, use that answer.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was just somewhat confused about encapsulation. The first link helped clear it up for me.

Comment: If you think this is the best answer, feel free to checkmark it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Attributes to an object shouldn't be static, for example your "name, actype, bal and amt". Also I think your money class should exist and those methods could be in a bank account (you deposit/withdraw from a bank account).